# CSS property "fit-content" disables "text-align

Tags: html, css

I am creating list items that need to display:

- an underline
- of a different color
- only when hovered
- that is the same size of the word, not the entire lis item
- the items need to be spaced around
  like in the picture attached
  [image: list items]
  So far, I managed that with the following code:
  (adding a span inside of the list item, and assigning it a "max-width: fit-content" on hover)

```css
ul {
    height: 40vh;
    width: 40vw;
    text-align: right;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
li span {
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    max-width: fit-content;
    
}
li span:hover {
    border-bottom: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <ul>
         <li><span>Who we are</span></li>
         <li><span>Brands</span></li>
         <li><span>Careers</span></li>
         <li><span>Contact</span></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

The issue is that the ul has to be aligned to the right. Before adding the needed property of `max-width: fit-content` to the `li span` tags, the `ul` was aligning to the right, but then. After adding the fit-content property, the `text-align: right` stopped working.

On the console, there is no indication of the `text-align` property not being properly compiled.

How can I achieve the result of having the underline, of a different color, the same width as the text it is underlining, when hovered, while the entire ul is aligned to the right?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: replace your width by margin-left:auto

Comment: ^ or get rid of the flexbox you are adding to the li and you don't need the margin or the width:fit-content

Comment: add `align-items: flex-end` to `li` in css.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov thank you so much! I am still getting familiarized with all the flexbox properties and somehow forgot about this one.

Comment: I am glad to help :)